# how to run the django server on hostname?

Tags: python, django, apache, python-2.7, django-deployment

I wanted to run Django server on a hostname in the local system. Django has its own server ... that runs on the `localhost:8000` i just want it to run on

```
cpanel-django.django-project.com:8000
```

I tried using:

```
python manage.py runserver cpanel-django.django-project.com:8000
```

i am getting this error:

```
Validating models...

0 errors found
March 06, 2014 - 06:21:24
Django version 1.6.2, using settings 'moclient.settings'
Starting development server at http://cpanel-django.django-project.com:8383/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit the hosts file and rename `localhost` to `cpanel-django.django-project.com`.

Comment: which host file ? is the system host file you are talking about /etc/hosts

Comment: Depends on OS. On most unixes, it will be /etc/hosts.

Comment: but it will change all the localhost to the name ..?

Comment: Hello from the future. You never want to change localhost. You want to add an alternative entry for the servername. So for example you'd have "127.0.0.1 localhost cpanel-django.djangoproject.com" as one line. Removing "localhost" will break any other application that communicates over localhost via hostname.

Answer (score 0):

For every host name there is mapping of IP address in your system so that you don't need to worry about IP address, you just need to remember host name.

How to add Host name in your system?

Check this wiki: [Host file content](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#File_content)

Where to find the file in your system?

Location of file in different system is mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_%28file%29#Location_in_the_file_system)

Answer (score 0):

For windows , you can make an entry in hosts file , located in

> C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

and update the file with

> 127.0.0.1               cpanel-django.django-project.com:8383

If you are running on port 80 ,

> 127.0.0.1               cpanel-django.django-project.com